# Passing Variables To Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do I pass variables into a Promise?

Here's the deal. I need a Promise that can be called by different functions. The Promise just sends an ajax request which finds the number of entries in a mySQL table and sets a global variable (var numberOfEntries = #).

The ajax request needs two variables in order to work.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
var request = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "grabDataFromSQL.php",
    data: { data1: variable1, data2: variable2 }
});
request.done(resolve(data));
```

So a function that uses the promise (essentially using the global variable), would look something like this:

```
function doSomeStuff() {
promise.then( // finish up here )
}
```

In order for the promise to work, it always needs those 2 variables. So... how do I go about this? Is there a way? Is my logic not right on this? I'm pretty stuck.

I can define the promise inside the same function that calls promise.then() and pass the variables into that function, however, I don't want to have to repeat all of that code over and over again when it always does the same thing.

Comment: This is just not the way to use a promise at all.  Promises are one-shot devices.  They can only ever have their state changed once and then are locked.  You should have each function that uses a promise either create it's own promise inside the function and return it or in the case of your ajax call, return the promise that the ajax call is already returning.

Comment: If you show the larger context of what you're really trying to do, we can show you the correct way to use promises to solve your issue.  Right now, all you've described is the problem you had with your solution, not the actual problem you're trying to solve.  That is known as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and is not the best way to get the best type of help.  We need to know the real issue you're trying to solve, independent of your current attempted solution.

Comment: Plus, the "sets a global variable" part of your solution is also probably not the right way to do things.  You should not need any global variables to make an ajax call and process the results.

Comment: I think you're confused with the word Promise. You don't "call" a promise, or pass something to it. You probably mean call a function to create a promise? And pass something to that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consideration:

1. Promise objects are not callable.
2. $.ajax returns a [jqXHR Object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which they tell me implements the Promise interface.

Hence I would try something like:

```
function myAjaxReq( data1, data2)
{   var o = {method: "POST", url: "grabDataFromSQL.php", data: {} };
    o.data.data1 = data1;
    o.data.data2 = data2;
    return $.ajax(o);
}

var promise = myAjaxReq( value1, value2);
promise.then( onSuccess, onFailure); // parameters are functions
```

Comment: So, does `$.ajax` return an object which supports `.catch`, which it would if it really "implements the Promise interface"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, while I was typing up my solution, Traktor53 gave me an awesome answer, which I'm going to accept. I'm still posting this alternative answer though in case anyone is interested, but Traktor53's answer is definitely the better one (much cleaner, and awesome find that $.ajax() returns objects that use the Promise interface now).

Here's my alternative answer:

Thank you jfriend00. You clarified some things for me. My solution was to create a function that creates and returns the promise. Then I could call this reusable function in other functions.

So, step one is to create the function that creates the promise which makes an ajax request for some data:

```
function findData(var1, var2) {
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "grabDataFromSQL.php",
    data: { data1: var1, data2: var2 }
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        resolve(data);
    });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Second step is to call the function whenever I need that data:

```
function doSomethingElse(var1, var2) {
    var promise = findData(var1, var2);

    promise.then(function(data) {
    // make another ajax request with the ajax data from promise
    }, function(error) { });
}
```

Comment: Actually, your answer is better than that of @Traktor53. You **should** wrap the result of `$.ajax` in a **real** promise, not the fake one that jQuery gives you. The only insight you needed was to create a function which returns the promise based on the values passed in. Actually, you should use `fetch`, but that's a different story.

Comment: @torazaburo, why is using jQuery's "fake" promise (I'm assuming it's some kind of extended Deferred object) bad & using javascript's "real" promise good?

Comment: Because real promises are real, and fake promises are fake.